# is system framework (like UIKIt.framework,CoreGraphics.framework) static library or dynamic library

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In xcode project, is system framework (like UIKIt.framework,CoreGraphics.framework) static library or dynamic library or something else?
Is it possible that use Mac OS X's framework (like Quartz.framework) in ios project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a dynamic library. Frameworks are Apple's way of packaging up a particular version of a dynamic library, along with its dependencies (such as header files). See the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html) for more information.

It is not possible to use a framework intended for OS X for iOS. (although there is some overlap; Apple makes frameworks with the same names that do essentially the same thing for both platforms, with some possible differences.) They must be targeted for the iOS architecture you want to use them on.

Comment: Also note that OS X frameworks are built for i386 (not counting old ppc frameworks) while iOS frameworks are built for armv7/armv7s (not counting the Simulator)